# OpenCL: could not find clRetainDevice in dll

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu, amd-processor

Using the AMD C++ binding and SDK (the most recent one) running an OpenCL program that gets a platform, a GPU, then compiles 4 kernels has the above error upon startup. It works fine on my computer, whose GPU only supports up to 1.1, but other computers seem to have the above error. Is this a problem in the compilation (As in, I have to define some macros), in the lack of a driver, the C++ binding, or something else? I don't explicitly call clRetainDevice in my own code—is it part of the binding somewhere?

Comment: clRetainDevice is defined only in OpenCL 1.2. Are you recompiling your program for the other computers? My guess is that while the AMD C++ bindings you are building against support OpenCL 1.2 (even though your *device* doesn't) but the runtimes on the other computers don't. That said, if you are not using clRetainDevice, this shouldn't be happening, so I'm guessing it's being called internally. Are you using subdevices?

Comment: I copied what I compiled to a different computer and just ran it.
I only use calls like getDevices() or Platform::get(), none of the fancy subdevices... >_>

Answer (score 2):

It happens when you use the C++ bindings header file with OpenCL 1.2 header. For instance, when you run an application compiled with AMD SDK (OpenCL 1.2) on NVIDIA platform (OpenCL 1.1 only).

As fast and dirty work around, you can just edit the AMD SDK cl.h header and undef "CL_VERSION_1_2" preprocessor symbol. If you are not interested to 1.2 features, it should fix your problem.

Comment: A problem occurs in that the compiler throws errors regarding the Image-related functions. I am really baffled. >_<

Comment: 1.2 redesigned the image API functions, so if you are not using 1.2 you should, as suggested, downgrade the headers to 1.1 and use the correct function (which is no longer `clCreateImage` but `clCreateImage2D`, `clCreateImage3D`, etc.. that's for the C bindings, at least, I *believe* the C++ bindings remain compatible but apparently not.